# EF 5 & MiniProfiler Issue

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, mvc-mini-profiler

I have a strange problem with EF5 and mini profiler.
Basically I have created a really simple project using the Blog/Post example.

If i do a linq command (for example, debug.writeline mycontext.Blogs.Count()) it works the first time, but then the second time around I get:

Unable to cast object of type 'StackExchange.Profiling.Data.EFProfiledDbConnection' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.

And the only way to resolve this is to rebuild the app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Changing my initialisation to MiniProfilerEF.Initialize_EF42() and moving it to the top of my App_Start sorted it